# Getting Average m:s:ms time in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am working on a Google Sheets file in order to get Track and Field Data.

The times run by the athletes are:

```
1:58.66
2:00.03
2:00.31
2:01.85
2:03.07
2:03.18
2:03.57
... etc.
```

In total I have 141 values. I have tried looking for functions to help me with this, but it seems as though these values are not accepted as numbers.

I need the average of all 141 times.

Comment: I found a tedious was of doing it by using:
=SPLIT(D2,".:") and  =M150*60+N150 & "." & O150

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to get this done in excel, but you can achieve it using the following function (assuming your data is stored in column `A`)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(sum(60*left(A1:A)+right(A1:A,5)))/COUNTA(A:A)
```

So, I used `arrayfunction` to go through the whole list at column `A` and converted it into seconds, then divided it by its count (using `COUNTA` for non-numeric values) to get the average seconds for all athletes.

You can export date in `mm:ss.00` format again using this function,

```
=TEXT(B1/(24*60*60),"mm:ss.00")
```

Please note that `TEXT` function receives value (in days), hence you will have to divide the first function result (assumed it is at `B1`) by `24*60*60`.

enjoy...